# How to find total activities in the stack history?

Tags: android

Could any plz tell how to find how many activites are currently in the history stack of the application ?

Comment: Why do you need to know?  What behaviour do you want your app to have that requires you to know how many are in the history stack?

Answer (score 4):

All activites in the history stack are maintained by the  activity manager 
you can find the history stack using activity manager
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html